# How to append values to the same array from two different functions?

Tags: python

Current Code

```
import multiprocessing as mu
import time

global_array=[]

def add_array1(array):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2.5)
        global_array.append(1)

        print(global_array)

def add_array2(array):
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        global_array.append(2)

        print(global_array)

def runInParallel(*fns):
      if __name__=='__main__':
        proc = []
      for fn in fns:
        p = mu.Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
      for p in proc:
        p.join()

runInParallel(
    add_array1(global_array),
    add_array2(global_array)
    )
```

When running my code above only the first function `add_array1()` is appending the value to the array and printing instead of both functions providing the wrong output:

```
[1]
[1,1]
[1,1,1]
```

When the actual desired output for the following code is:

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,1,2]
```

Comment: you are calling the functions, you  probably need to provide them only:

Comment: what do you mean? I need them to run simultaneously as well.

Comment: `runInParallel(add_array1(global_array),add_array2(global_array))` EXEcutes the functions _not_ in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the function call

```
runInParallel( add_array1(global_array), add_array2(global_array))
```

executes the functions and provides the *return value* of the function calls as parameters to `runInParallel`. As `add_array1` is an endless loop, it never returns from the execution. You need to provide your functions as *functions* - not the returnvalue of the functions as parameters to `runInParallel(...)`

Start with

```
runInParallel( add_array1, add_array2) # name of the functions, dont execute em
```

and change

```
def runInParallel(*fns): 
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        p = mu.Process(target=fn, args=(global_array,)) # provide param here
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()
```

and then fix the "not joining" problem due to your threaded functions never returning.

---

Example from [the official documentation of multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

> ```
> from multiprocessing import Process 
> import os
>
> def info(title):
>     print(title)
>     print('module name:', __name__)
>     print('parent process:', os.getppid())
>     print('process id:', os.getpid())
>
> # Function name is f
> def f(name):
>     info('function f')
>     print('hello', name)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     info('main line')
>     # f is provided, and args is provided - not f("bob")
>     p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
>     p.start()
>     p.join()
> ```

Comment: so are you suggesting that I don't give it parameters just call the function and let it append to the global_array?

Comment: @Philip See the quoted example from the documentation for how to call/provide a function that takes parameters

Comment: @philip Your function have endless loops, they will _never_ return - so they will also _never join_. You need to fix that as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the code below to get your desired output:

```py
import threading
import time

global_array = []


def add_array1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2.5)
        global_array.append(1)

        print(global_array)


def add_array2():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        global_array.append(2)

        print(global_array)


def runInParallel(*fns):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        p = threading.Thread(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runInParallel(
        add_array1,
        add_array2
    )
```

Comment: I already have the ```if __name__=='__main__':``` in my runInParallell() function.

Answer (score 0):

***you can use this simple code to get your desired output:***

'''

```
import time


global_array = []


def add_array1(array):


    while True:
        time.sleep(2.5)
        if len(global_array) % 2 == 0:

            global_array.append(1)
            print(global_array)
    
        else:
            global_array.append(2)
            print(global_array)


add_array1(global_array)
```